# Shouldnt the tostring in a python xml element from an elementtree return a proper text?

Tags: python, xml, tostring, elementtree

I am using tostring in order to transform a xml element tagged "p" into a string.

```
result=lxml.html.tostring(child, method="text", encoding='utf8') #child is the given element
```

While on the browser it renders properly as a line:http://jsbin.com/AnoYePA/1/edit

The result string I get from this operation consist of several lines with one word each.

So the question is,shouldnt the "result" string be one lined, same as it renders in the internet browsers?

The element I apply this operation is attached in the pastebin.

Comment: As a side note, you don't need to use the `tostring` function with `method="text"` here, you can just use the `text_content` method on the node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it shouldn't.

There are newlines in the text of the node. You're asking lxml to extract the text of the node, which includes that whitespace.

A web browser renders any run of whitespace as a single space, so those newlines aren't visible, in the output. But that's a feature of how HTML is rendered, not of the text. The fact that lxml doesn't reproduce that rendering is no more "wrong" than the fact that the text doesn't have the same fonts, boldfacing, etc. as it does in your browser.

If you want to reproduce HTML's whitespace compression, you can do that pretty easily—e.g., `re.sub('\s', ' ', s)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Not only this fixes my problem but perfectly helped me understand clearly why it is this way.